# Javascript Array push a "title"

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, push

I want to create a Javascript array by adding the individual parts to the array using the push function.

This also works so far:

the creation of the array:

```
var buildProduktion = new Array();
```

and here the individual arguments are defined and added to the array via push:

```
var singleString = {step: 1, name: sName.value, description: sDescription.value, lon: sLon.value, lat: sLat.value, ficon: sIcon.value, img: filePathName}

buildProduktion.push(singleString)
```

I repeat this step with different data so that this array is created in the end:

```
[
 {step: 1, name: sName.value, descri...},
 {step: 2, name: sName.value, descri...},
 {step: 3, name: sName.value, descri...},
 {step: 4, name: sName.value, descri...},
 {step: 5, name: sName.value, descri...},
 {step: 6, name: sName.value, descri...}
]
```

but I would like to name the arrays like shown below:

```
"ExampleName":[
  {step: 1, name: sName.value, descri...},
  {step: 2, name: sName.value, descri...},
  {step: 3, name: sName.value, descri...},
  {step: 4, name: sName.value, descri...},
  {step: 5, name: sName.value, descri...},
  {step: 6, name: sName.value, descri...}
]
```

but I don't know how to do it with push or something like that...

The problem is actually relatively simple and has probably already been answered somewhere, but I just don't know the right keywords to look for

Comment: `var buildProduktion = { ExampleName: [] }`, then `buildProduktion.ExampleName.push(...)`…

Comment: When you loop through an array you can count the indexes (steps), you don't need to store the index in the object from what it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is living inside an object named arrayObject.

```
let arrayObject = {
ExampleName:[]
}

arrayObject.ExampleName.push(singleString);
```

this will add strings to the Examplename array of arrayObject

I hope below standalone example code will make you understand better

```
let step = 'step'

let arrayObject = {
    ExampleName: []
}
let singleString1 = { step1: 1 }
let singleString2 = { step2: 2 }
let singleString3 = { step3: 3 }

arrayObject.ExampleName.push(singleString1);
arrayObject.ExampleName.push(singleString2);
arrayObject.ExampleName.push(singleString3);

console.log(arrayObject);
```

Comment: but is it possible to rename "ExampleName" in the "arrayObject" using a variable? so that I get the information e.g. from an input field in html and this variable then replaces the "ExampleName".

Comment: Arrays in javascript are a reference type. This means you can declare another variable and point it to the array by using                               
         `arrayObject.ExampleName = arrayObject.yourPreferredName`   This code will declare an array called "yourPreferredName" and point it to "ExampleName" array

Answer (score 0):

seems like you want to create a javascript object, and store the array inside.
but this is not part of the array itself.
all you need is:

```
const someObjName = {
"ExampleName":buildProduktion
}
```